# Ordering map legend items in Wikidata Query Service

Tags: leaflet, sparql, openstreetmap, wikidata-query-service

Wikidata provides a [cool way](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:SPARQL_query_service/Wikidata_Query_Help/Result_Views#Map) to render SPARQL results on OpenStreetMap. For [example](https://query.wikidata.org/embed.html#%23Big%20cities%2C%20grouped%20into%20map%20layers%20by%20population%0A%23defaultView%3AMap%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%20%28SAMPLE%28%3Flocation%29%20AS%20%3Flocation%29%20%28MAX%28%3Fpopulation%29%20AS%20%3Fpopulation%29%20%28SAMPLE%28%3Flayer%29%20AS%20%3Flayer%29%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2A%20wd%3AQ515%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Flocation%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP1082%20%3Fpopulation.%0A%20%20FILTER%28%3Fpopulation%20%3E%3D%20500000%29.%0A%20%20BIND%28%0A%20%20%20%20IF%28%3Fpopulation%20%3C%201000000%2C%20%22%3C1M%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20IF%28%3Fpopulation%20%3C%202000000%2C%20%221M-2M%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20IF%28%3Fpopulation%20%3C%205000000%2C%20%222M-5M%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20IF%28%3Fpopulation%20%3C%2010000000%2C%20%225M-10M%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20IF%28%3Fpopulation%20%3C%2020000000%2C%20%2210M-20M%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3E20M%22%29%29%29%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20AS%20%3Flayer%29.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel):

```
#Big cities, grouped into map layers by population
#defaultView:Map
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?cityLabel (SAMPLE(?location) AS ?location) (MAX(?population) AS ?population) (SAMPLE(?layer) AS ?layer)
WHERE
{
  ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515;
        wdt:P625 ?location;
        wdt:P1082 ?population.
  FILTER(?population >= 500000).
  BIND(
    IF(?population < 1000000, "<1M",
    IF(?population < 2000000, "1M-2M",
    IF(?population < 5000000, "2M-5M",
    IF(?population < 10000000, "5M-10M",
    IF(?population < 20000000, "10M-20M",
    ">20M")))))
    AS ?layer).
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
GROUP BY ?city ?cityLabel
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to control the order of the items in the legend (top right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that [leaflet](/questions/tagged/leaflet) tries to parse layer names as numbers. In case of failure, the order of layers in the legend corresponds to the order of the first appearance in the table (switch between "Map" and "Table" views).

Thus, you should bind additional variable with naturally sortable values (and then sort results by those values). Perhaps this is possible using `REPLACE`, but I'd prefer to use simple dictionary.

```sql
#--Big cities, grouped into map layers by population--
#defaultView:Map
SELECT DISTINCT ?city ?cityLabel
(SAMPLE(?location) AS ?location) (MAX(?population) AS ?population)
(SAMPLE(?layer) AS ?layer) {
    VALUES (?layer ?order) {
    ("<1M" 1) ("1M-2M" 2) ("2M-5M" 3) ("5M-10M" 4) ("10M-20M" 5) (">20M" 6)}
    ?city wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q515;
          wdt:P625 ?location;
          wdt:P1082 ?population.
    FILTER(?population >= 500000).
    BIND(
    IF(?population < 1000000, "<1M",
    IF(?population < 2000000, "1M-2M",
    IF(?population < 5000000, "2M-5M",
    IF(?population < 10000000, "5M-10M",
    IF(?population < 20000000, "10M-20M",
    ">20M")))))
    AS ?layer).
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
} GROUP BY ?city ?cityLabel ORDER BY (SAMPLE(?order))
```

[Try it!](https://query.wikidata.org/#%23Big%20cities%2C%20grouped%20into%20map%20layers%20by%20population%0A%23defaultView%3AMap%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%0A%28SAMPLE%28%3Flocation%29%20AS%20%3Flocation%29%20%28MAX%28%3Fpopulation%29%20AS%20%3Fpopulation%29%0A%28SAMPLE%28%3Flayer%29%20AS%20%3Flayer%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Flayer%20%3Forder%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%28%22%3C1M%22%201%29%20%28%221M-2M%22%202%29%20%28%222M-5M%22%203%29%20%28%225M-10M%22%204%29%20%28%2210M-20M%22%205%29%20%28%22%3E20M%22%206%29%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fcity%20wdt%3AP31%2Fwdt%3AP279%2a%20wd%3AQ515%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP625%20%3Flocation%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20wdt%3AP1082%20%3Fpopulation.%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%28%3Fpopulation%20%3E%3D%20500000%29.%0A%20%20%20%20BIND%28%0A%20%20%20%20IF%28%3Fpopulation%20%3C%201000000%2C%20%22%3C1M%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20IF%28%3Fpopulation%20%3C%202000000%2C%20%221M-2M%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20IF%28%3Fpopulation%20%3C%205000000%2C%20%222M-5M%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20IF%28%3Fpopulation%20%3C%2010000000%2C%20%225M-10M%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20IF%28%3Fpopulation%20%3C%2020000000%2C%20%2210M-20M%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22%3E20M%22%29%29%29%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20AS%20%3Flayer%29.%0A%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Fcity%20%3FcityLabel%20ORDER%20BY%20%28SAMPLE%28%3Forder%29%29)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I guess you can also order final data (e.g., `order by ASC(?population)`) and get the same result.

Comment: @floatingpurr, yes, I have overcomplicated :). However, the approach from the answer works for pure categorical data too.